# JavaScript cannot insert images into HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm making a prototype for a program that lets you insert an image URL and you can add to it with animated GIFs (Canvas is not used because animated GIFs cannot be shown). However, when I try to do this, it doesn't work.

```
<center>
<input type="text" id="tb" placeholder="Image URL" />
    <button onClick="ipt()">Import</button>
    <button onClick="edit()">Add Effects</button>
    <div id="lyr">

    </div>

</center>

<script>
    function ipt() {
    var c = document.getElementById('tb').value;
    alert(c);
    document.getElementById('lyr').style.background = "url(" + c + ")";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you answer, please do not use jQuery code ($).

Comment: What does the `alert(c)` give you?

Comment: the alert is a test just to see if the function is being called.

Comment: I mean do you have a valid URL? Does it work if you hardcode that same URL in the CSS?

Comment: Your issue is probably just that your `div` element has no dimensions or content, so it's collapsed down to nothing. Works if you give it some structure. http://jsfiddle.net/g2a00uLp/

Comment: it doesn't work in css. Not sure why, and infact I just defined a width and height,

Comment: Then the path maybe isn't right. What happens if you type the path directly into the browser's location bar?

Comment: I got it! It was a CSS problem I defined width and height without the 'px'!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. FYI, the `<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML5. better to use something else and center the content with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple vanilla script that'll do what you want.

It first creates variables for each of the items you want to handle, then creates a click handler for the button.

Feel free to swap out the class selectors for IDs.

https://jsfiddle.net/chxd6bnb/2/

```
var holder = document.getElementsByClassName('holder');
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('showIt');
console.log(button);

button[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var img = image[0].value;

    holder[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img + ')';
});
```